# Looking for a mobile app looking css/JavaScript toolset

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking around for a toolset like bootstrap which will make a website look and act like a native app.

Only basic functionality is required

Is such thing available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many such frameworks available:

1. Ionic: [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)
2. Mobile Angular-ui : [mobile angular-ui](http://mobileangularui.com/)
3. Sencha touch
4. Kendo-ui
5. Phonegap/Cordova

`Ionic` and `Cordova` are very popular for native looking applications.